# can i use ton required params in roure

Tags: laravel, routes

I use this syntax in route

```
Route::get('/pro/f/{f_id}/m/{m_id}/g/{g_id}', 'FunController@index');
```

And I want to use this without "f" for example

https://example.com/api/pro/m/1/g/2 - not found

https://example.com/api/pro/f/33/m/1/g/2 - it work

I want to use both variants for this route.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Use two routes?

Comment: i think about this. But i have  next situation i have 10 parameters. 9 of than can be or can except. In this case i need to use al combination of routes.

Comment: Do those parameters need to be in your route? What about query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as many required params in route as you want.

All your params are required in your route and of course "f", "m" and "g" are required too, otherwise it points to another route.

If you want to have optional parameter it must be placed at the end of the route

In this case I thing you have to define another route to have access with https://example.com/api/pro/f/33/m/1/g/2

For example:

```
Route::get('/pro/f/{f_id}/m/{m_id}/g/{g_id}', 'FunController@withAllParams');

Route::get('/pro/f/{f_id}/g/{g_id}', 'FunController@withoutM');

Route::get('/pro/f/{f_id}/g/{g_id}', 'FunController@withoutF');

Route::get('/pro/f/{f_id}', 'FunController@withoutG');
...
//etc
```

If you want to be fully universal route and define only one I would prefer to do this in this way:

> I don't recomend to do that

```
Route::get('/pro/{id1?}/{id2?}/{id3?}', 'ExampleController@fullParams');
// Controller
public function fullParams(Request $request, ...$ids) {
    $f_id = $g_id = $m_id = null;

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $letter_name = $id[0];
        $var = $letter_name . '_id';
        ${$var} = substr($id, 1);
    }

    echo "f: $f_id, g: $g_id, m: $m_id";
}

// Example route
http://example.com/pro/f23/g22/m44     => "f: 23, g: 22, m: 44"
http://example.com/pro/f23/m44         => "f: 23, g: null, m: 44"
http://example.com/pro/m44             => "f: null, g: null, m: 44"
http://example.com/pro/m44/f33         => "f: 33, g: null, m: 44"
...
// you can do any route configuration you want
```

Hope this helps you